# SQL join query help - data validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with two columns, city and area in a SQL Server 2008 DB. There are 9 distinct area values that apply to each city. For example, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999. So the table would look like

```
 city,area
 city1,111
 city1,222
 .... 
 city1,999
 city2,111
 city2,222
 .....
 city2,999
 etc...
```

I would ideally like a result set with the city and the missing area for each one. Is there a way to write a select statement that would do this?

I realized that not each city has all 9 values, there are 61 cities that are missing at least one value, however I can't seem to identify which value is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Create all combinations of `city` and `area`, then use a `left outer join` to find the missing values.

```
select c.city, a.area
from (select distinct city from cityarea) c cross join
     (select distinct area from cityarea) a left outer join
     cityarea ca
     on ca.city = c.city and
        ca.area = a.area
where ca.city is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

please tell if for any sample data it don't work.

```
declare @t table(city varchar(50),area int)
insert into @t values('city1',111),('city1',222),('city1',444),('city2',111),('city2',222),('city2',333)
,('city2',444),('city2',555),('city2',777)
;with CTE as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by city order by area)rn from @t
)
select * from cte a 
inner join cte b on a.city=b.city and b.rn-a.rn=1
where b.area-a.area>111
```